# And clause to use condition date time SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

*I am using this method to get data :-*

```
declare @date varchar(30),@time varchar(20);
set @date = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(), 102), '.', '-');
set @time = FORMAT(getdate(), 'HH:mm');

select j.JourneyID,j.Source
        from journeytb j left join usertb u on j.userid = u.userid 
        left join TravelerTypeTB traveler on j.TravelerType = traveler.SrNo             
            where 
                j.UserID = @user_id

                and j.StartDate >= (case when (@start_date is null) then @date when @start_date is not null then @start_date else @date end)
                and j.StartTime >= (case when @start_time is null then @time when @start_time is not null then @start_time else  @time end)
```

*I want to check both date and time lets say i check current date if it is less than the date from the table column then its is true and same case for time **issue here is if the date is within time frame then its true if the time is not then false which doesn't give data from table i want to check date then time within this 'AND' clause** or is their any other way around*

Comment: Removed the MySQL tag as having most likely been added to gain attention.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected results?

Comment: We can really help you if you add some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two separated values for date and time, couldn't you solve this more easily by concatenating them back into a single `DATETIME` format and comparing that?  Ex:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE -- Example table with data
(
     StartDate VARCHAR(10)
    ,StartTime VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('01/01/2017','10:15');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('02/02/2017','11:25');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('03/03/2017','15:05');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('04/02/2017','06:00');

DECLARE @CURRENT AS DATETIME;
SET @CURRENT = GETDATE(); -- The parameter you're checking against

SELECT *
FROM @TABLE 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,StartDate + ' ' + StartTime) < @CURRENT -- Concatenated full DATETIME compared to the parameter
;
```

Returns only those dates from the table that are less than the value you're checking.

Of course you could play around with this to do it a bunch of different ways...

Comment: @rinki If you don't mind, could you mark the response as the answer if it worked for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How abou this?

```
and
(
    (
    j.StartDate = (case when (@start_date is null) then @date when @start_date is not null then @start_date else @date end)
    and j.StartTime >= (case when @start_time is null then @time when @start_time is not null then @start_time else  @time end)
    )
    or
    j.StartDate > (case when (@start_date is null) then @date when @start_date is not null then @start_date else @date end
)
```

Comment: Thank you this method might help me get through with the issue.